# Windows 8 App reading and/or copying locked file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am writing a Windows 8 App (as the title says) and I want to be able to copy a file used by another program when it is done being written but still being used.  Windows Explorer does not allow copying of the file because it says it is in use by another program.  I have googled this problem extensively and everyone says to use `System.IO.FileStream` to accomplish the task.  However, because I am using a Metro App, that is not an option.  How else can I accomplish this task?

**Update:**
Here is what I have tried so far

```
//FAILED TO READ LOCKED FILE
//await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
//await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
//await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
//await file.OpenReadAsync();
//await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync();
//await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
//await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
//await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(file);
//await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my answer!  Using `await file.CopyAsync(storageFolder);` I created a copy of the file without issue